# Typescript: conditional type does not work

Tags: typescript

I am developing a graphql schematizer and i can not continue because the next conditional type does not work

```js
type VarType = 'Boolean' | 'Float' | 'Id' | 'Int' | 'String';

type TypeValue<Type extends VarType> =
  Type extends 'Boolean' ? boolean :
  Type extends ('Float' | 'Int') ? number :
  Type extends ('Id' | 'String') ? string :
  never
;

type TypeValueDeclaration<Type extends (VarType | [VarType])> = Type extends [VarType]
  ? Array<TypeValue<Type[0]>>
  : TypeValue<Type> // Type 'Type' does not satisfy the constraint
;
```

how can i do make work the type `TypeValueDeclaration`

---

it will be used like this

```js
interface FieldInfo<Type extends (VarType | [VarType])> {
  type: Type,
  resolver: () => TypeValueDeclaration<Type>;
}

function addInfo<Type extends (VarType | [VarType])>(info: FieldInfo<Type>) {
  console.log(info);
}

addInfo({
  type: 'Int',
  resolver: () => 3.14,
});

addInfo({
  type: 'Int',
  resolver: () => '10', // compilation error :+1
});

addInfo({
  type: ['Int'],
  resolver: () => [1, 2, 3],
});

addInfo({
  type: ['Int'],
  resolver: () => ['lol'], // compilation error :+1
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error in your conditional type can be resolved by spelling out each possibility:

```
type TypeValueDeclaration<Type extends (VarType | [VarType])> = Type extends [VarType]
    ? Array<TypeValue<Type[0]>>
    : Type extends VarType ? TypeValue<Type> : never
    ;
```

You might assume that the compiler should understand that `Type extends VarType` must be true at that point, but [unfortunately it does not, at least for now](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132).

---

Also note that it is not necessary to use conditional types when mapping from string literals to types, since ordinary object types can do that:

```
type TypeValue<Type extends VarType> = {
    Boolean: boolean, Float: number, Int: number, Id: string, String: string
}[Type];
```

But it's up to you.

---

Oh well, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwCrmgXigcgEIHtcA2EcAdplAD5YBiBucw5VmAkgCZNYsmOVYDKwBAEsSAc0wBuAFDTQkKCkjwCAVwgAeJdAgAPYBBJsAzrETaAfFAwBvaVAdQ8hYiQBcUAEb4ipADRQtPTAHiSqALaeEAgB3CFQYZHRsWwexkKiYgGCIuJpGeLSAL4A2toAujJyqIqoKuoAIhAAxgSIDMK4JFo1egZGpgAU8Mg1VCUjFQCUVhjaUH2GJlAT5qjl9o4A-FAAgggIcCA9ynBqmtolAAzlFhabDh7ziwNmowo72vUXqFahEAA3aIPKBVUQGBAAMzgzWg1GEEAIbG4kNwJx0+iWQ0mYxWOMg5RmUDsjig8ggT1QfhBCAgxkIQIQHkGU2sVi+Z0aLTah2AnW6lhkRVkkNUJGafK6UDgbGRJFR6IWmNewzWCnG+IghIsg1EqI88MRcoVllZJMczS69KIADo6GJdfLcFMhbIZcbcINzQ5yR5WDxMNTSbTrYzmay0FYAMw2gCMABZqUUXW7ZSjPd6yag-XFAzS6QzouG2VhY1dA1AAPSVqCW8JgYRtSUkBYHXAIKBuADUseKKek7vTXpBvpW-sY5SDjhDhaZUBZJZKsYCACYAlHJ32qoOncPSaOSuPMJvgwWCGH5xGrIe6ARjwFq7XcPXGx0pdEEO3Oz2t0A)

Comment: thanks men, this fixes my error and I appreciate your suggestion, I will use it